# react/redux map function doesnt return the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have problem with returning a values from map function. I'm getting data from my database as an array of objects. Fetching em with an action like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.props.fetchArticle();
}
```

Im returning data like this: (this is just an example to see if its working)

```
if(this.props.article) {
  const articles = this.props.article.data;
  console.log(articles); // here I got my data, as in the screenshot
  articles.map((article => {
    return (
      <div>
      Title: {article.title} <br/>
      Img: <img src={article.img} style={{height:100}}/> <br/>
      Author: {article.author.username} <br/>
      Desc: {article.desc} <br/>
      Content{article.content} <br/>
      Add date: {new Date(article.addDate).toLocaleString()} <br/>
      </div>
      )
  }));
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You just need to return the result of the `map` call.

Instead of

```
articles.map((article => {
....
```

you need

```
return articles.map((article => {
....
```